# Lost git decoration in VSC when adding the changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Git decoration is really helpful. However, in the new version of VSC something has changed. Now, when I use "git add" the decoration of lines (green, blue or red for new/changed/deleted lines) disappears, when previously this happened only after change committing. Any idea of how can this be controlled? Haven't found anything in the settings

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have:

- the latest VSCode 1.61.2
- a local repository (no network path or UNC path) for testing
- settings like `workbench.editor.decorations` (badge/colors) selected

It should work (I don't reproduce the issue on my side)

There was a [recent issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133754)